# I'm trying to use a button to go to another scene, but its giving error, javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a button work, but when I click it, it gives an error
Here's the error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3564)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8200(Scene.java:3492)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3860)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyMouse(MacView.java:127)
```

Here's the controller I'm using

```
package HMS;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private PasswordField tf_pfield;

    @FXML
    private Button btn_login;

    @FXML
    private TextField tf_uname;

    @FXML
    private Button Doc_adPan;

    @FXML
    private Button Lab_adPan;

    @FXML
    private Button Pharma_adPan;

    @FXML
    private Button Finance_adPan;

    @FXML
    private Button Settings_adPan;

    @FXML
    private Button Staff_adPan;

    @FXML
    private Button Logout_adPan;

    @FXML
    private Button Wards_adPan;

    @FXML
    private void handlebuttonclicks(javafx.event.ActionEvent mouseEvent)
    {
        if(mouseEvent.getSource() == Doc_adPan)
        {

        }
        else if(mouseEvent.getSource() == Lab_adPan)
        {

        }
        else if(mouseEvent.getSource() == Logout_adPan)
        {
            loadStage("Login.fxml");
        }
        else if(mouseEvent.getSource() == Staff_adPan)
        {

        }
        else if(mouseEvent.getSource() == Settings_adPan)
        {

        }
        else if(mouseEvent.getSource() == Pharma_adPan)
        {

        }
        else if(mouseEvent.getSource() == Finance_adPan)
        {

        }
        else if(mouseEvent.getSource() == Wards_adPan)
        {

        }
    }
    private void loadStage(String fxml)
    {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxml));
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.hide();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the FXML file where the button exists.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<VBox prefHeight="742.0" prefWidth="845.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="HMS.Controller">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane onMouseClicked="#handlebuttonclicks" style="-fx-background-color: white;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="Doc_adPan" layoutX="344.0" layoutY="159.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonclicks" onMouseClicked="#handlebuttonclicks" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="123.0" prefWidth="62.0" stylesheets="@Styles.css" text="Button" />
            <Button fx:id="Lab_adPan" layoutX="532.0" layoutY="175.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonclicks" onMouseClicked="#handlebuttonclicks" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="123.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="Button" />
            <Button fx:id="Pharma_adPan" layoutX="724.0" layoutY="163.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonclicks" onMouseClicked="#handlebuttonclicks" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="123.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="Button" />
            <Button fx:id="Finance_adPan" layoutX="344.0" layoutY="332.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonclicks" onMouseClicked="#handlebuttonclicks" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="123.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="Button" />
            <Button fx:id="Settings_adPan" layoutX="528.0" layoutY="332.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonclicks" onMouseClicked="#handlebuttonclicks" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="123.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="Button" />
            <Button fx:id="Staff_adPan" layoutX="722.0" layoutY="329.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonclicks" onMouseClicked="#handlebuttonclicks" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="123.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="Button" />
            <Button fx:id="Logout_adPan" layoutX="756.0" layoutY="18.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonclicks" onMouseClicked="#handlebuttonclicks" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="Button" />
            <Button fx:id="Wards_adPan" layoutX="334.0" layoutY="502.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebuttonclicks" onMouseClicked="#handlebuttonclicks" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="123.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="Button" />
            <Pane layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="743.0" prefWidth="249.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DFF6F0 #DFF6F0;">
               <children>
                  <Text layoutX="91.0" layoutY="140.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Welcome!">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="17.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Text>
                  <Text layoutX="112.0" layoutY="157.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="USER" />
                  <Text fill="#1273ba" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="482.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Sharif Surgical Hospital">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Text>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="110.0" fitWidth="125.0" layoutX="62.0" layoutY="310.0">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../sss/mainLogo.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <ButtonBar layoutX="174.0" layoutY="92.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="89.0" />
            <Text layoutX="441.0" layoutY="81.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Admin Panel" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="220.0">
               <font>
                  <Font size="36.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Text layoutX="767.0" layoutY="95.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Logout" wrappingWidth="53.66004199452357">
               <font>
                  <Font size="16.0" />
               </font></Text>
            <ImageView fitHeight="75.0" fitWidth="75.0" layoutX="334.0" layoutY="163.0">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../sss/doctor.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fitHeight="75.0" fitWidth="75.0" layoutX="524.0" layoutY="163.0">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../sss/Lab.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fitHeight="75.0" fitWidth="75.0" layoutX="717.0" layoutY="161.0">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../sss/Pharmacy.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fitHeight="75.0" fitWidth="72.0" layoutX="336.0" layoutY="332.0">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../sss/Finance.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fitHeight="75.0" fitWidth="75.0" layoutX="522.0" layoutY="329.0">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../sss/settings.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fitHeight="75.0" fitWidth="75.0" layoutX="715.0" layoutY="332.0">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../sss/Staff.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fitHeight="75.0" fitWidth="75.0" layoutX="334.0" layoutY="502.0">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../sss/Wards.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fx:id="Logout_adPan1" fitHeight="40.0" fitWidth="40.0" layoutX="771.0" layoutY="25.0">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../sss/logout.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Text layoutX="346.0" layoutY="278.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Doctor">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Text layoutX="548.0" layoutY="278.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Lab" wrappingWidth="30.958903300616043">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Text layoutX="727.0" layoutY="278.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Doctor">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Text layoutX="346.0" layoutY="437.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Finance">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Text layoutX="528.0" layoutY="437.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Settings">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Text layoutX="727.0" layoutY="437.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Staff">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Text layoutX="347.0" layoutY="611.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Wards">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Here's the FXML file to which I'm trying to go to using the button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="370.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="HMS.Controller">
   <children>
      <Text fill="#1273ba" fontSmoothingType="LCD" layoutX="67.0" layoutY="286.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" style="-fx-font-size: 20; -fx-font-family: Times New Roman;" text="Sharif Surgical Hospital" />
      <Text layoutX="430.0" layoutY="89.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Welcome to login page!" />
      <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="79.0" layoutY="85.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../sss/mainLogo.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="331.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="325.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1273ba;">
         <children>
            <PasswordField fx:id="tf_pfield" layoutX="122.0" layoutY="233.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="152.0" promptText="Enter Password" style="-fx-background-color: white;" />
            <Button fx:id="btn_login" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Login" textFill="#1273ba" />
            <Text fill="WHITE" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="208.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" style="-fx-font-size: 16;" text="Username" />
            <Text fill="WHITE" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="251.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" style="-fx-font-size: 16;" text="Password" />
            <Text fill="WHITE" layoutX="138.0" layoutY="154.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" style="-fx-font-size: 20;" text="Login" />
            <TextField fx:id="tf_uname" layoutX="122.0" layoutY="192.0" prefWidth="152.0" promptText="Enter Username" style="-fx-background-color: white;" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here's the main

package HMS;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AdminDashboard.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the logout button(Logout_adPan). I've added all references and this was built using scene builder. I don't know what am I doing wrong

Comment: unrelated: java naming conventions, please!

Comment: you have same controller for both dashboard and login - that's bound to break sooner or later because the one doesn't know about the fields injected by the other (not entirely certain if that's the cause here, though). Also: why _hiding_ the login stage after loading? Anyway, what we need is a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (mind the __M__ , nothing unrelated)

Comment: and now at the end, seeing the error: you use the same method reference for both mouse handler on parent and action handler on button - they have different signatures, so loading them will blow at one of them :) Which probably is what the answer tries to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to compare two objects using the symbol `==` while you have to do it using the method `equals()` which will return true if they are equal, otherwise it will return false. 
Don't forget to cast `mouseEvent.getSource()` to `Button`
try this:

```
 if(((Button)mouseEvent.getSource()).equals(Doc_adPan))
{

}
else if(((Button)mouseEvent.getSource()).equals(Lab_adPan))
{

}
else if(((Button)mouseEvent.getSource()).equals(Logout_adPan))
{
    loadStage("Login.fxml");
}
else if(((Button)mouseEvent.getSource()).equals(Staff_adPan))
{

}
else if(((Button)mouseEvent.getSource()).equals(Settings_adPan))
{

}
else if(((Button)mouseEvent.getSource()).equals(Pharma_adPan))
{

}
else if(((Button)mouseEvent.getSource()).equals(Finance_adPan))
{

}
else if(((Button)mouseEvent.getSource()).equals(Wards_adPan))
{

}
```

and Use only `onAction="#handlebuttonclicks"`, not `onMouseClicked`.

and remove `onMouseClicked="#handlebuttonclicks"`  from `AnchorPane`

Comment: you have to do it for all the code, I edited my answer, copy and paste it

Comment: @Saad and Use only `onAction="#handlebuttonclicks"`, not `onMouseClicked`

Comment: @Saad and remove `onMouseClicked="#handlebuttonclicks"`  from `AnchorPane`, you have Actions only on Buttons ..

Comment: After removing the onMouseClicked, the error is gone but the button is not working anymore

Comment: btw, `==` vs. equals doesn't matter here, same result. But well spotted error :) At OP: as already commented to your question - time for a [mcve] .. though I think the _not working_ is a _seemingly_ not working due to hiding the loaded stage :)

Comment: and as  @kleopatra already commented, you have to use one controller for each fxml page

Comment: @kleopatra why it doesn't matter here?

Comment: because they are the same instance - that's what default equals is implemented anyway

Comment: @Saad why do you make `stage.hide();` ? I think this is your problem, you want to show a new page which you are hiding it

Comment: Thank you very much, removing onMouseClicked worked. The next mistake as @kelopetra was saying that I used stage.hide().